# How to remove widget from another Qwidget?

Tags: qt

i created one QWidget(Parent). in the inside of the parent widget i created another one QWidget(Child). In the run time i need to remove the child widget. how to do that?

i am not using any layout. i am directly putting in the Parent Widget.

Please Help me to fix this.

Comment: i found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940409/how-to-clear-all-the-widgets-in-parent-widgets

Answer (score 8):

If you add the widget with e.g.:

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget(parent);
```

...then you can remove it with:

```
delete w;
```

Another approach would be to just hide it:

```
w->hide();
```

Comment: but i don't know the name of the child widget (in run time also i am creating child widget). how to i find and delete it?,

Comment: const QObjectList & children () const. It's a QObject's method. You can use to get the children. Or you can simply store a pointer to your widget (which one you want to delete)

Answer (score 7):

*This answer is for those arriving from search engines and want an answer to the question as stated in the title.*

If you want to remove a child from a parent without deleting it or hiding it (which does NOT remove it from its parent), set the child's parent to `NULL`.

```
QWidget::setParent(NULL)
```

Note that explicitly reparenting a widget like this carries several implications (e.g visibility automatically set to hidden). See `QWidgets` [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) for more information.

Comment: After 2 hours of google-fu I found this gem, that really removes (but doesn't delete) a widget from a layout. Now `this->ui->myLayout->removeWidget(myWidget);` is obsolete, too. Thanks for making me continue my web-dev-escapist Qt-app.